# How to copy nicely the fields from a base class into the dervived class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a base class `A` and a derived class `B`.
How can I copy...in a single simple line...the fields from an object of type `A` into an object of type `B`?
I have a method,if that helps,that can build the object from the field values.
I do not want to use any type of reflection!

```
class A{
  String id; //and setter/getter
 }
class B extends A{
  String b; //and setter/getter
}
public A buildA(String id){
  A=new A();
  a.setId(id);
  return A();
}
// how to copy A=buildA("a") into a B type of object...
// I would avoid doing 
//public B voidB(String id, string b){
B=new B();
b.setId(
b.setB...
// Remark - I cannot do the init from constructor with fields!
```

Comment: You just need a copy method in class `B` which copies the values from `A`: `public void copy(final A a)`.  Then just write out all of the copying in that single method inside of `B` and you would just call `B b; A;`, init `A` and `B`, then just call  `b.copy(a);` whenever you want to copy `A` into `B`.

Comment: Why don't you do the copiing in the Constructor?

Comment: Why? Why do you want the same data twice?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Please clarify your question, because i cannot understand what you wnat.  Why don't you create a `buildB` method that builds B?

Comment: @markusw If you do the copying in the constructor, then you can only create a _new_ object.  If you create a method which can overwrite this object, (the copy method), then you can reuse this object instead of filling up the heap with a bunch of new `B` objects every time you want to copy an `A` into a `B`.

Comment: @Jared: But his `buildA` method creates also new objects. So this is no argument. Except from that if you do not reference these created objects they get gced anyway...

Comment: @markusw He didn't have that there when I made my comment (or I hadn't seen that edit yet).  You're right--the way the OP has it, they should just have constructors for both `A` and `B` which take a `String` (or the constructor for `B` could take an `A` object).

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/), which might help you (i haven't tried it, though).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for, or am i on the wrong track?

```
public B buildB(A a,String str){
b=new B();
b.setId(a.getId());
b.setB(str);
return B;
}
```

Comment: that is where I want to get, but in a stylish way:)

Comment: Do the copying in the constructor! There is no other way with pure Java

Comment: @Roxana.. markusw is right, either the way i've written or copying in constructor are only two ways to do this(as per my knowledge)...stylish way should not be an excuse to reject a solution. :/